# Combine data from two sensor android

Tags: android, sensors

I have a accelerometer that Points a Arrow the way I tilt the phone, and I have a prximity that shows a image in different state when I have my hand near the sensor. I want to combine so that if I tilt the phone to the right and also hold my hand over the proximity sensor something will happend.

```
ImageView is;
ImageView iv;
private Sensor mAccelerometer;
private Sensor myProximitySensor;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    is = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    final SensorManager manager;
    SensorEventListener listener;

    manager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    listener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            Sensor sensor = event.sensor;

            if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {


                float x = event.values[0];

                float y = event.values[1];

                float z = event.values[2];

                if (Math.abs(x) > Math.abs(y)) {

                    if (x < 0) {
                        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.right);



                    }

                    if (x > 0) {

                        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.left);

                    }

                } else {

                    if (y < 0) {

                        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.up);

                    }

                    if (y > 0) {

                        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.down);

                    }

                }

                if (x > (-2) && x < (2) && y > (-2) && y < (2)) {

                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.center);

                }
            }
            else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {

                if(event.values[0]==0 ){
                    is.setImageResource(R.drawable.near);



                }else {
                    is.setImageResource(R.drawable.far);

                }


            }


        }
    };
    manager.registerListener(listener, manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    manager.registerListener(listener, manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}
```